# Capital gothic letter in headings

Tags: header-footer, capitalization

One of the section of my thesis is called: representation of `$\mathfrak{g}_2$`, but every heading package transforms it in representation of `$\mathfrak{G}_2$` (capital Gothic letter).

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: I think `\MakeTextUppercase` from `textcase` package is intended exactly for this.

Comment: There is a completely non-TeXnical solution to your problem: Follow traditional style guides and avoid formulae and symbols from formulae in the chapter titles and headings.

Answer (score 9):

LaTeX's standard classes use `\MakeUppercase` to convert the letters of section titles to uppercase. The conversion does not know about arguments, math, ...

Workarounds:

- The letter "g" can be hidden inside a macro, e.g.:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\mathfrakg}{\mathfrak{g}}
  \pagestyle{headings}
  \begin{document}
  \section{Test $\mathfrakg_2$}
  \end{document}
  ```

  > [image: Result]

  `\DeclareRobustCommand` prevents `\makefrakg` from expanding inside `\MakeUppercase`.
- Converting back to lowercase:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \pagestyle{headings}
  \begin{document}
  \section{Test $\mathfrak{\lowercase{g}}_2$}               
  \end{document}
  ```

  First `\MakeUppercase` will change `g` to `G`. Later `\lowercase` is executed and converts `G` back to `g`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `textcase` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\section{Test $\mathfrak{g}_2$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the best is to avoid the dreaded automatic uppercasing done by the standard classes, which is, in my opinion, the biggest flaw in their design. When headers contain math, uppercase is out of the question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Test $\mathfrak{g}_2$}
\end{document}
```

[image]